# How to fix angular js ng-controller function call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a basic angular js module where I am passing the module and the controller message in a separate script file. The issue I am facing is it does not print the message defined in the called function. This seems to me might be an issue with the ng-app defined.

Here is the code :

**module.html**

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "D:\Educational\angularJS code\script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="myController">
    {{ message }}       
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the called script.

**script.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule",[]);

var myController = function($scope){
$scope.message = "Angular JS";
}

myApp.controller("myController", myController);
```

The only thing that gets printed in the format is  {{message}} and NOT the actual message "Angular JS".

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: may be not injected script.js file

Comment: that might be a possibility, but i have kept the script file in the same page as the html itself, should not be a calling issue i guess

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your ***script.js*** in the same folder just include it simply by

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

make sure you have internet on your computer since you are using a ***CDN***

**Note: please check your console by pressing `ctrl+j` or `f12` to see if there are any errors**

---

You can also try putting your code into the markup itself for now and check if the code works fine.

```
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myModule",[]);

    var myController = function($scope){
       $scope.message = "Angular JS";
    }

    myApp.controller("myController", myController);
<script>
```

Comment: yep, worked, changing it to just script.js worked, Thanks!!